# Is It Possible To Handle Packet Loss, Sending Media Stream?

Tags: webrtc, buffer, packet, loss

Using WebRTC via Chrome browser.

WireShark detected packet loss for sending media stream(video, audio).
I want to know way to control sending buffer, or release packet loss.

I couldn't search anything about sending buffer.

---

Without using DataChannel.

Comment: Is there any other ways, without using DataChannel?

Comment: AFAIK, all of the packet loss are handled by WebRTC natively, the best you can do is turn on or off flexible forward error correction, other than that, you'd have to dig into the source code. What exactly are you trying to achieve? Maybe there's something else that can deal with that.

Comment: I thought, video broken problem caused by the loss of sending packets. So, I wanted to adjust sending buffer.